# Statistics reference books (handbooks) contain all the formulas and easily understood for non-math people

Tags: references

I am a graduate student in imaging genetics. When I have a statistics questions and search online and can often find answers. However, I cannot cite User Generated Content. Can you suggest some reference books contain all the formulas for all the formulas of common statistics methods?

For example, I have recently read [an answer about the formula for calculating SE of predictor variable (x)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236437/how-to-compute-the-standard-error-of-a-predictor-variable). But I cannot find the formula in books like *[Handbook of Regression Analysis](https://www.google.com.sg/books/edition/Handbook_of_Regression_Analysis/X95obhB6RQcC?hl=zh-CN&gbpv=1&dq=since%20values%20farther%20from%20the%20centroid%20are%20harder%20to%20predict%20as%20precisely.%20Specifically,%20for%20a%20simple%20regression,%20the%20estimated%20standard%20error%20of%20a%20predicted%20value&pg=PA1973&printsec=frontcover)* (I can only see formula of SE of y).

Comment: What is UGC? You are just looking for stats books that are easy to read for laymen?

Comment: Why not ask your prof

Comment: @AdamO My prof is not majored in statistics.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand I want a book for formulas.

Comment: At this point, we have scores of threads listing [tag:references]. The duplicate seems like a good place to start, but if it doesn't have what you're looking for, we have many, many more available via search.

Comment: In any discipline there's nothing the matter with relying on a handbook *once you understand the discipline itself.* However, the implicit notion in this question that statistics is a matter of looking up and applying formulas is woefully misguided: therein lies the difficulty with answering this question.